# SQL to set Display Name to First Name + Last Name

Tags: users, sql, wp-user-query

I'm trying to set the wp_users.display_name for a rather larger users db using SQL query.

Got till this point:

```
SELECT x.display_name, x.first_name, x.last_name
FROM
(SELECT
  u.display_name,
  f.meta_value AS 'first_name',
  l.meta_value AS 'last_name'
FROM
  wp_users AS u
INNER JOIN
  wp_usermeta f ON f.user_id = u.ID
INNER JOIN
  wp_usermeta l ON l.user_id = u.ID
WHERE f.meta_key = 'first_name'
AND l.meta_key = 'last_name') AS x;
```

But trying to change the first SELECT statement to an UPDATE doesn't work:

```
UPDATE
  wp_users
SET
  display_name = CONCAT(x.first_name, ' ', x.last_name)
FROM
(SELECT
  u.display_name,
  f.meta_value AS 'first_name',
  l.meta_value AS 'last_name'
FROM
  wp_users AS u
INNER JOIN
  wp_usermeta f ON f.user_id = u.ID
INNER JOIN
  wp_usermeta l ON l.user_id = u.ID
WHERE f.meta_key = 'first_name'
AND l.meta_key = 'last_name') AS x;
```

Comment: Do you have access to WP CLI? If so this can be made much easier/faster, a raw SQL query won't invalidate caches or fire hooks which can cause problems. That SQL query also won't leave a separator between the first and last names

Comment: Thanks for the tip Tom. I just installed WP CLI. And what would be the WP CLI command to reset the display_name for all users?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the SQL query that can be used to reset the `display_name` to `first_name + last_name`. And it's simpler than the `JOIN`s that I was trying when I posted the question.

```
UPDATE wp_users 
SET display_name = Concat(
    (SELECT meta_value 
     FROM   wp_usermeta 
     WHERE  meta_key = 'first_name' 
     AND user_id = id
    ),
    ' ',
    (SELECT meta_value 
     FROM wp_usermeta 
     WHERE 
     meta_key = 'last_name' 
     AND user_id = id
    )
);
```